# Compiler error when assigning the Delegate for a Protocol in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, delegates, swift, protocols

I have a problem assigning the delegate for an object that is an instance of a class that defines a protocol in Swift as follows:

I simplified the code to the bare bones to exemplify the issue:
This is the class with the protocol

```
protocol TheProtocol {
    func notifyDelegate()
}
class ClassWithProtocol: NSObject {   
    var delegate: TheProtocol?
    fire() {
        delegate?.notifyDelegate()
    }
}
```

This is the class the conforms to the Protocol

```
    class ClassConformingToProtocol: NSObject, TheProtocol {
        var object: ClassWithProtocol?
        func notifyDelegate() {
            println("OK")
        }
        init() {
            object = ClassWithProtocol()
            object?.delegate = self  // Compiler error - Cannot assign to the result of this expression 
            object?.fire()
        }
    }
```

I have tried all sort of alternatives to assign the delegate without success.  Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Known Issues section of the Release Notes says:

> You cannot conditionally assign to a property of an optional object.
>   (16922562)
>
> For example, this is not supported:
>
> ```
> let window: NSWindow? = NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow
> window?.title = "Currently experiencing problems"
> ```

So you should do something like `if let realObject = object { ... }`