# Swift Optional Chaining with Objective-C Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, swift

In B4, they changed `IBOutlet`s to be optionals (rightly so…).

But as a result, let's say you have an `UIImageView`. It will be declared a `UIImageView?` due to it being a `IBOutlet`.

Consider the following Obj-C code:

```
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
```

Because the swift code's `myImageView` is an optional, it seems like I should be able to do:

```
myImageView?.image(UIImage(named:"someImage"))
```

But I can't. I get

> '(UIImage) -> $T6' is not identical to 'UIImage'

I can do:

```
myImageView?.setValue(UIImage(named:"someImage"), forKey: "image")
```

Just fine but that's stringly typing and just plain dumb.

So what I have to resort to is this:

```
if let iThoughtSwiftWasSupposedToBeLessVerbose = myImageView {
    iThoughtSwiftWasSupposedToBeLessVerbose.image = UIImage(named:"someImage")
}
```

What's going on here? Even in the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_357) it says that methods can be called on optionals. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax you are looking for is `myImageView?.image = ...` and, as mentioned in the release notes, this is not *currently* supported. It is tracked by rdar://problem/16922562. You may wish to [file a duplicate](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I agree with @jtbandes. Alternatively, you can make `myImageView` an implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`).

Comment: @jtbandes where is the question that this a duplicate of?

Comment: @Jacob You can find the link at the top of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899867/compiler-error-when-assigning-the-delegate-for-a-protocol-in-swift-ios

Comment: @Jacob Hmm, it is hard to see. [Let's see if this goes anywhere...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236965/can-question-status-have-a-different-background-color-than-blockquote-pre)  (I'm not going to post an answer here because it's just a duplicate of the other question, which I already answered...)